# Wordpress editor: lock editing part of page

Tags: wordpress, post, permissions, editor

My client wants to edit pages content in Wordpress. I had to disable visual editor because it ruins custom html. The problem is my client isn't familiar with HTML.
What I want is to lock part of source code in WP editor for ex. in line

```
<div class="whatever">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

I want to allow him to modify only "Lorem ipsum" part.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

well you can provide a `textarea` for him to enter text and then replace html inside element with class `whatever`, so basically you control regions of html where modifications can be made instead of whole page, of-course you need to write some code to do so.

I would simply mark the editable regions with some kinda class, and then on page load add some script which will pick all regions with that clas and show a small editable button there, on click of those button a shim with text area would pop up where user can add his text/html and on done, the markup would be injected inside the element. Later on save, the whole page would can be saved, little tricky but can work :)